# How to stream Raw AAC data to android mediaplayer?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any way to stream raw AAC data to android media player? Or i there any work around for that?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this post   http://vaclavb.blogspot.com/2010/06/raw-aac-player-for-android.html. Might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Warning: You need to pay AAC decoding royalty if you intent to publish your app.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Update to the above blog post: http://vaclavb.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/raw-aac-player-for-android-2.html , there also a new lib from Vaclav Bartacek that encapsulates just the decoder; 
https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/